# How to backreference using inline typescript type variables

Tags: typescript, variables, generics, parameters, backreference

I have implemented the built in generic `Omit` which relies on the generic `Exclude`.

```
type MyExclude<C, E extends C> = C extends E ? never : C

type MyOmit<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  [p in MyExclude<keyof T, K>]: T[p] //Returns object with unwanted properties omitted
}
```

At the moment I cannot successfully implement `Omit` without first declaring an `Exclude` generic and consuming it within `Omit`. An attempt to do so throws an error.

```
type MyOmitInLine<T, K extends keyof T> = { 
  [p in (keyof T extends K ? never : keyof T)]: T[p] //Returns complete object
}
```

However, I would like to implement `Omit` without consuming on any other generics, and I believe the key to doing this is by:

1. declaring a type variable inline
2. back referencing to the declared type variable

Like so:

```
type MyOmitWish<T, K extends keyof T> = { 
  [p in ((keyof T as C) extends K ? never : C)]: T[p] //What I want -- is this possible?
}
```

Please is this possible?

[Link to use this code in the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=46&ssc=2&pln=34&pc=1#code/PQKgUABBDMELQQPIFsCWAXS8491gRgJ4QCCAdugBYD2ZxAYgK4QAUAAgIYUBmjAlBADEyAKYATVI2RDGZVLSH5GqADbo4qMliyDdEAIqMRAZ3TytULAElkABxUjRFCFREQlq9ZogADFBgAeABUAGggAaQA%20HwgAcxEyEQAnVABjCAB3DBpGdAhGY01YiAwAOm0oAGFaUyTGVPRjCA4XQls3IghbNIBrIuaVFS6k6naksxMIbhHpHyCYrjEXSgSIJMdqADd%20n3CfCoh6aiSIEQAPDjsHA59bxqxNdGTuDlS3IOoxaggAbywoMzoBwALggtSK-wgYhMqRStjMtFB4LIsUhqWoVxETzEoPw1GoDi4WAAvgd0G13p9qAAFdbbEQZCAAXggAFlCP50MEqWEAOTQ4yw1Dw8y8iAAHwgvMBDl5kQO6LIphcVNBHy%20tJE9MZLL%20UCg6Mx2NBLxUxhEIRJWFu%200sUEiEAAaqgGRAFABxDAACUY%20FBlHQ6FsxmBwGAjVSlFKACtjKVjrFgNAwCBgGB06AIAB9HO5vO5iAATWojBO1WhEC9yTc%20drOYgqfT5PabMIAFEzqkVIxoQFKmE26czk8yGImpUHSzKkOR2OIIOAPwQRKbZIQUGVJsU1uc4JhcIzhJznoiQjUbgQIKT35YADathKZFbHa7PZEARPZ4voQikQAumq95-hAYYAEpYqWSpuvg0YiA0mTZPkZAZFw2LDKMyQTE0GIYNiYCkmAzZuOynJWGQAAymjvj%20B7nLOTSfuel7Xj8EB3g%203gsIx36HqOTQHkuK5rqC3GXnwAGXkBIHAOB6CQU0hr2FibjUDBcGYARRE7mg6AAOqoMYlB7hEvHHqeTFXsyvxsVA96PqwXHmTxHDjgIdFHvxECCVqwkQJU4mAbYwFhrplAcHkViZKh2AlE0VAGV01DGIU%20AOAu%20EZsArQtiROnGbRw4eRAomWSymXZcRHJ5TRpkMU5zFWblgQ0WEJWRH8Yb6nZ3jsi%203a9iV%207-oFf5gJ1mnbk8yosk16BkZRiTcl8fICkKIq0HK6ZjSA2Z1vml4mHklQuZMe37Y2qB2MceRaaxbYAI6MBwKgDmc7TwcSUwzFKbBEXAkbPQ4KImMAuSqMYvJbi2qQnU0LK3lgHbvVyD1PSoARI%20p4gAIxhLNS3UCtMJwgiZBypEkSWlAmMNBjj3PRjb1Y2IABMeNVc1PJSqtJOihKUqKQ42Lk5TYCjWNWW-cYcDnMjMtJCMSSEduySK41HNcuqhPc8Twqk2Kkq8pomzPagYibWAjzPK8lJfDeAIYCCYLoCkKJYDzevmEiLsQgaGJKca7j4oSWgEVbSQvG885Mw0OP2y4jsiN7ruon7RriLiwciESYcUNbUc09iLPxzKSfOynGVbZmZ15ocpauCcADKTzBrtNdZg2aagFgDqN2F6wQGepZggSYM1P6gbBqG4aClGsbxkkibQMAXDGBkyQ906LqMsYo%20kyGEABkGIZhhGc9xgmSbALv3b75vrLHG4lRhYMCTxAfR9T6fs8xhfi8pmmMAQA)

**UPDATE**

I found [something which is exactly what I was hoping for](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/issues/9835) but I don't understand it just yet:

```
type MyOmit<T, U extends keyof T> = {
  [P in keyof T as P extends U ? never : P]: T[P] //works without erros
}
```

Comment: `P extends U` is the same behavior/idea as `C extends E` in `MyExclude`. It's just that the definition of `MyExclude` is inlined, as you wanted.

Comment: Thanks @catgirlkelly. Are you able to spot the gap in understanding that led me to reach for a new variable `C` instead of asserting on the existing variable `'p'`. I know for one, it seems like I tried to assert one type as `<another type which doesn't exist>`, which I can imagine shouldn't allowed. But the `P as P` assertion is also confusing, mainly because I don't understand where `(` and `)` can be placed in a way the the expressions still work. So I probably don't understand TS expressions fully and would love pointers to better understand.